# How to collect LLDP information on Windows?

Tags: windows, ethernet, service-discovery

Or, another question, what is Microsoft LLDP Protocol Driver and how do I use it?

I am fully aware of what LLDP is and use it with Linux and switches on a regular basis. What I'm trying to do it collect the same information I can get from lldpd or open-lldp on Linux on a Windows box. I assume it should be possible with the Microsoft LLDP Protocol Driver, otherwise, I have no idea what that driver is for. Currently, I have that driver enabled on my desired interface, I have LLDP enabled on the switch it's attached to, and I can see incoming LLDP frames as expected from that switch when running Wireshark on that interface. I would expect that the LLDP driver is either responsible for generating outgoing LLDP frames, parsing incoming LLDP frames, or both. I don't see any outgoing frames and I can't find any information about configuring the driver with details for LLDP so I suspect it's more for parsing incoming frames which is the more useful scenario and what I need. However, again, I can't seem to find any APIs, WMI classes, or other methods for querying any information collected by that driver if that is what it's doing. Where is the documentation for exactly how that driver is to be used?

I have found workarounds to this issue where Wireshark is run in the background for up to 90 seconds waiting for the next incoming LLDP frame, but that is unacceptable for my use case especially when multiple different adapters are included. I would like an agent similar to lldpd that keeps a cache of recent LLDP frames up to the TTL they advertise it should be so the date is immediately available when requested. It seems like something documented Microsoft LLDP Protocol Driver should do that, but the documentation is quite sparse on the matter.

Comment: https://github.com/lahell/PSDiscoveryProtocol ?